# Redrawing legend when the figure is closed

Tags: python, matplotlib, event-handling, legend

Using matplotlib, I'm trying to execute a callback function when a figure is closed, which redraws the figure legend. However, when I call ax.legend(), it seems to block any further code being executed. So in the code below, 'after' is never printed.

Could someone explain why this is? And is it possible for me to run code after the legend() call, but before the figure closes? The ultimate goal is to save two different versions of a figure when it is closed, redrawing the legend in between saves. Thanks.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def handle_close(evt):
    f = evt.canvas.figure
    print('Figure {0} closing'.format(f.get_label()))
    ax = f.get_axes()

    print('before')
    leg = ax.legend()  # This line causes a problem
    print('after')  # This line (and later) is not executed

xs = range(0, 10, 1)
ys = [x*x for x in xs]
zs = [3*x for x in xs]

fig = plt.figure('red and blue')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.plot(xs, ys, 'b-', label='blue plot')
ax.plot(xs, zs, 'r-', label='red plot')

fig.canvas.mpl_connect('close_event', handle_close)
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, sorry, I have figured it out. `f.get_axes()` returns a **list** of axes objects. So the later call to `ax.legend()` doesn't work correctly.

Changing to the lines below fixes the problem:

```
axs = f.get_axes()
for ax in axs:
    leg = ax.legend()
```

I'm still not sure why this didn't produce some kind of interpreter error though.